# OSX available OpenGL ARB extensions

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-3

from http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1072_Core.html appears that current OSX 10.7.2 core OpenGL support is still limited at 3.20 with GLSL 1.50

among other data are the available ARB_ extensions.

I was wondering if these were the *minimum guaranteed* to be present extensions, or if you really have **only** these four, namely:

```
ARB_instanced_arrays
ARB_occlusion_query2
ARB_shader_bit_encoding
ARB_timer_query
```

Im currently developing a portable application that should run on OSX and uses ARB_separate_shader_objects, does it mean it will definitely not run on OSX 10.7.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those, plus the extensions [that are part of the legacy profile](http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/index.html), are the only extensions currently available with Apple's drivers for the drivers/graphics cards listed on those pages.

Comment: definitely bad news, but thnx anyway